# Use minio for storing attachments of an android application

Tags: android, hardware, attachment, capacity, minio

Im trying to use minio as I want to use minio for self-host instead amazon S3 in my android application, so my yml file configuration look like this :
s3:
accessKey: 1PAVK1425juiUAH
accessSecret: inhoKJSHDUIIrichskiY7Fpc9
attachmentsBucket: bucket
endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:9000
region: us-east-1
pathStyleAccess: true
signerAlgorithm: AWSS3V4SignerType
but it doesn't work, when I try to send an attachment the signal application give my this error "signal has stoped" .
any one have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

The way to calculate storage capacity is based on number of objects to be uploaded and cater for a future window so that you don't run out of disk space.

Start with calculating what will be the average file size and total number of objects to be uploaded. This would give you an effective disk capacity that you need.

Minio is fully self contained comes in single binary,  you can run locally or in the cloud like (DigitalOcean, packet.net) etc.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your reply!

Comment: Harshavardhana:!